# How is CultureInfo.CurrentCulture determined?

Tags: c#, windows, cultureinfo, culture

I have a computer in Israel. I deployed an MVC website to the computer's IIS. In this website I show the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (for my needs) and it shows "he-IL".

I changed:

> Control Panel > Region and Language > Formats

to **English (US)**.

Also I changed

> Control Panel > Region and Language > Administrative > System Locale

to **English (US)** and of course restarted the computer.

But `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` still shows me "he-IL"!

How can I change it without touching the code - only by setting or changing the system? (Windows 7)

I need to be dynamic and not hard-coded.

Comment: Do you set `Thread.CurrentCulture` or `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` anywhere in your code? `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` depends on that.

Comment: No, I don't touch it anywhere

Comment: Changing the system locale is supposed to work.  But he-IL is pretty special due to the right-to-left layout.  Ask at superuser.com