# Where is CurrentCulture retrieved from in C# application

Tags: c#, server, regional-settings

I have an application deployed across several servers

When I display `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` using `System.Globalization`, some sites display `en-GB` and some `en-US`

Where is this setting being picked up from? On a server that displays en-US, the region settings are English (United Kingdom) and the Language preferences have English (United Kingdom) ahead of English (United States)

Many thanks

Comment: What is the actual question behind this? It's almost certainly already answered. `CurrentCulture` is your user's culture setting. For desktop applications, it's provided by the OS. For web applications it's determined by the user's preferred language in the browser, application-level settings, request overrides, and a fallback to the service account's locale which is typically the server locale. Different web sites use different strategies with eg forum sites allowing users to store their preference in their profile while corporate apps use a single setting

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583257

Comment: @Orace not quite - it's more specific but still unclear, which is why it got no answers. Localization is already covered in the docs extensively

Comment: As the good book says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-6.0#how-a-threads-culture-is-determined Essentially it comes down to a call to [`GetUserDefaultLocaleName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename). Where *that* comes from is a different question...

Comment: Globalization and Localization is covered **extensively** in the docs, for all possible stacks - Winforms, Webforsm, UWP, MVC, Razor pages, WPF. For ASP.NET Core, check [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Notice step #3: `Implement a strategy to select the language/culture for each request`. There are several built-in features and techniques, but *you* have to decide what's best for your site first.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The application is identical in terms of code and config on each server. When you say `and a fallback to the service account's locale which is typically the server locale` this is the numb of my question - I cannot see anything on the server or in the registry that relates to `en-US` so am at a loss to see where the application is retrieving this from.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's important to note that the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is a [by thread static property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute).

Based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=net-6.0#how-a-threads-culture-is-determined), if there is no user interventions, the original value is retrieved from a call to [GetUserDefaultLocaleName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename) (on windows systems).

Possible user interventions are:

- Set the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property.
- Set the `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture?view=net-6.0).